# Find the installation directory of OpenCv

Tags: opencv, directory, installation

I need to find the installation directory of OpenCv so that I can add it's path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH so I can run OpenCv programs the problem is I don't know where to look for it since I'm completely new to ubuntu.

I'm using ubuntu 10.04
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can add following lines to /etc/bash.bashrc using your favorite text editor so that you dont have to export path everytime.

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

and restart your system.